# WP7 Expression Blend generates outdated sample data

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend-4

I have a data class in my C# project and when I try to generate some sample data in Expression Blend 4 it uses my some sort of oudated version of my class which creates the problem that my newly added properties aren't gernerated in the sample data and some removed properties are.

I tried restarting VS and Expression Blend 4, Clean and Rebuild and done that like 8 times over again.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: What steps do you take to generate the sample data in Blend?

Comment: Is the object you are referencing in another DLL

Comment: I use the function "Create Sample Data from Class" and no it's not in a seperate DLL. But today I tried it again and it worked so maybe it was my computer reboot that fixed it...

Answer (score 1):

Expression Blend uses **Debug** builds of your code for design-time and sample-data generation.

So if you're building as **Release**, it won't notice the changes.